# How to get value of JArray dictionary by key

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mono, virtual-reality

I have this json string:

```
[
   [
      {
         "Antibiotic after diagnosis":[
            "Azithromycin",
            "Ciprofloxacin HCl",
            "Ampicillin Sodium"
         ],
         "City":[
            "Tel Aviv",
            "Jerusalem"
         ]
      }
   ],
   [
      {
         "Antibiotic after diagnosis":"Azithromycin",
         "City":"Tel Aviv"
      },
      {
         "Antibiotic after diagnosis":"Ciprofloxacin HCl",
         "City":"Jerusalem"
      }
   ]
]
```

I deserialized this string:

```
data = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<object>>("*json str*");
JParameters = data[0] as JArray;
Debug.Log(JParameters["Antibiotic after diagnosis"]);
```

But when i run the code it crashed on the line (Debug.Log(JParameters["Antibiotic after diagnosis"]);) with the following error:

> "ArgumentException: Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "Antibiotic after diagnosis". Int32 array index expected."

Comment: `JParameters = data[0] as JArray;` -> You have an array. "Antibiotic after diagnosis" is a property of each item in that array, not a property of the array (arrays themselves can't have properties), hence the error.

Comment: What do you want to receive? The value of "Antibiotic after diagnosis" for each of the objects or just the first?

Comment: @razerez Depends on your desired outcome ...

Comment: look closely, the json is a list that has 2 arguments in it, the first is a dictionary of lists and the second is a list of dictionaries i want to get the value of the first item in data[0]-> "Antibiotic after diagnosis" which is "Azithromycin"

Comment: JParameters[0]["Antibiotic after diagnosis"] is what you want. You have another array inside the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index into `JParameters` should be an integer as the error states.  What you want is:
`JParameters[0]["Antibiotic after diagnosis"]`

The above code selects the first element, and then selects the value for the dictionary key "Antibiotic after diagnosis".

I recommend reading [w3schools JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp) to properly understand how JSON works.

Comment: No need to be unfriendly, especially if your answer is wrong as well. 
`JParameters = data[0] as JArray` and therefore is already the first element of the outermost list.

Comment: @derpirscher I've flagged your comment. Aaron's answer is neutral, not unfriendly. The tone of your own comment, however, _is_ unfriendly.

Comment: @derpirscher I see what you mean. I tested the above JSON array as is and without taking into account the `data[0]` line. I have updated my answer

Comment: @john  Personally I read an answer like "read x to properly understand how y works" without pointing out a specific error as "you are too dumb, so I won't take any time to explain it" And why is my comment unfriendly? It's at least as neutral as Aaron's

Comment: @derpirscher Based on previous exchanges, I'm going to abstain from commenting further. As already stated, his answer is neutral.

Comment: @john I'm not sure when this "previous exchanges" happend but there is a saying "Communication is what arrives at the recipient" and to me it seemed unfriendly. If it's not unfriendly for you, it's ok. If my comment seems unfriendly to you, it's also ok ...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to get key, value from Jproperty.

```
var files = JArray.Parse(YourJSON);
foreach (JArray item in files.Children())
 {
      foreach (JObject obj in item.Children())
        {
           foreach (JProperty prop in obj.Children())
            {
               string key = prop.Name.ToString();
               string value = prop.Value.ToString();
            }

        }
 }
```